# Is it ok to use sudo in capistrano scripts?

Tags: sudo, capistrano3

I started messing with Capistrano recently. There are many articles on the Internet about Capistrano deployment scripts that use sudo. However, if someone gets my Capistrano script with sudo user credentials, he can potentially do everything on the server (just like the root user). So, I wonder if there's real need for the deployer to have sudo privilegies.

For example, If I use Rails, rbenv, puma, nginx, foreman and deploy on Ubuntu. My Capistrano deployer user could have only permissions to manage `/var/www/appname` dir. Rbenv doesn't use gemsets and installs gems in `/var/www/appname/shared/bundle`. Foreman can export to upstart session jobs: `~/.init` instead of `/etc/init`, so it doesn't need sudo either. I can also [run Nginx as a non-sudo user](https://www.exratione.com/2014/03/running-nginx-as-a-non-root-user/). Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You can make capistrano work without giving `deployer` user sudo permissions. This is explicitly mentioned in [capistrano docs here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#authorisation).

> That means we need to be able to work, ideally without sudo (none of
>   the default Capistrano recipes expect sudo to be available)

I think a lot of the users (myself included) aren't that concerned with `deployer` user having sudo privileges because we enable 'passwordless' ssh login and do some server hardening.

Other thing you mentioned:

> ... if someone gets my Capistrano script with sudo user credentials..

You don't have `deployer` user password hardcoded somewhere in `deploy.rb` right? That would be a bad practice.

Capistrano encourages users to setup passwordless ssh authentication [link to capistrano docs here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#authentication). It is really worth the effort to learn how to set that up. That knowledge will serve you a long time and it is more secure than sshing with a password.

Comment: No, of course I don't have any password in my deployment script) In addition to your answer, if passwordless sudo is allowed for some scripts (services), the scripts should have only execute permissions. So, if someone, for instance, steals my laptop, he'll not be able to modify the scripts and put there any harmful content.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with rbenv, puma, systems, ngingx and capistrano 3.
https://github.com/tomjoro/puma_jungle_rbenv_cap3